# System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.dll in vs2008

Tags: c#, windows, using

i need this System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.dll to run charting application in vs2008 windows application

Comment: I got this assembly i install MSChart.exe file after that i will copy the System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.dll after that i uninstall that MSChart.exe.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [this](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=130f7986-bf49-4fe5-9ca8-910ae6ea442c&displaylang=en)?

If not, then basically, I have no idea what your question is.